# Piggy Bank Python -Dictionary

Tags: python

I need to return a tuple of values of coins with their count in this Piggy Bank Dictionary problem but I am not getting the result.

```
def piggyBank(coin_list):

    count['Q']={} #Initializing the dict
    count['D']={}
    count['N']={}
    count['P']={}
    value=0
    for coins in coin_list:
        if coins in count['Q']:
            count['Q']+=1
            value+=25
        if coins == 'D':
            count['D']+=1
            value+=10
        if coins == 'N':
            count['N']+=1
            value+=5
        if coins == 'P':
            count['P']+=1
            value+=1
    return (count, value)
```

I don't know why it's not working.

Here is the sample input:

```
>>> piggyBank(['D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'P'])
({'Q': 2, 'D': 2, 'N': 0, 'P': 3}, 73) 

>>> piggyBank(['D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N'])
({'Q': 0, 'D': 2, 'N': 3, 'P': 0}, 35) 

>>> piggyBank(['P', 'D', 'N', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D'])
({'Q': 3, 'D': 3, 'N': 4, 'P': 3}, 128) 

>>> piggyBank(['D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'P'])==({'Q': 2, 'D': 2, 'N': 0, 'P': 3}, 73)
True
```

Comment: could you print the error string(if any) as well as some sample input?

Comment: Here is the sample input :  >>> piggyBank(['D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'P'])
({'Q': 2, 'D': 2, 'N': 0, 'P': 3}, 73)
>>> piggyBank(['D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N'])
({'Q': 0, 'D': 2, 'N': 3, 'P': 0}, 35)
>>> piggyBank(['P', 'D', 'N', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q',
'D'])
({'Q': 3, 'D': 3, 'N': 4, 'P': 3}, 128)
>>> piggyBank(['D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'P'])==({'Q': 2, 'D': 2, 'N': 0,
'P': 3}, 73)
True

Comment: Perhaps it's better if you edit your post and add the data into your post

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to walk through the errors you get (there are several) and hopefully give some explanation of the issues so that they will help you to understand what is wrong with the program. Learning to understand error messages takes some practice.

First:

```
    count['Q']={} #Initializing the dict
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Before you can say `count['Q']` you need to initialize `count`. Is it a string? A float? A list? Python doesn't know. So you are going to have to tell it that `count` is a dictionary. For example, you could do `count = {}` as the first line or you can initialize the entire dictionary in one line. There are plenty of resources discussing this all over the internet.
Based on your current code you should be able to do something like this once it's initialized properly:

```
print(count)
{'Q': {}, 'D': {}, 'N': {}, 'P': {}}
```

Once you address that error an initialize your dictionary, the next error you will get is this:

```
  File "coins.py", line 33, in piggyBank
    count['D']+=1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'int'
```

You have defined `count['D'] = {}`, that is a [dictionary within a dictionary](https://linuxhint.com/python_dictionary_of_dictionaries/). But what is `{} + 1`? It doesn't make sense. If you want to added one at a time, it makes more sense to initialize each dictionary entry as `0`, so that when you look at your variable it looks like this:

```
print(count)
{'Q': 0, 'D': 0, 'N': 0, 'P': 0}
```

Okay, so let's say we've fixed that. You're going to come across another error:

```
    if coins in count['Q']:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

For some reason, your if statement for quarters is different from the others, so you'll need to fix that. But the error message is saying *if `count['Q']` is an integer, I can't check if `coins` is in it.* However, your other conditional statements are formatted in a way that works.

If you correct all of these errors, then your code should run as you expect:

```
print(piggyBank(['D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'P']))
({'Q': 2, 'D': 2, 'N': 0, 'P': 3}, 73)
print(piggyBank(['D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N']))
({'Q': 0, 'D': 2, 'N': 3, 'P': 0}, 35)
print(piggyBank(['P', 'D', 'N', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Q', 'D', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'D']))
({'Q': 3, 'D': 3, 'N': 4, 'P': 3}, 128)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir. I will try to run it as you instructed.